# SVM Matlab classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I'm approaching a 4 class classification problem, it's not particularly unbalanced, no missing features a lot of observation.. It seems everything good but when I approach the classification with fitcecoc it classifies everything as part of the first class. I try. to use fitclinear and fitcsvm on one vs all decomposed data but gaining the same results. Do you have any clue about the reason of that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few recommendations:

- Have you normalized your data? SVM is sensitive to the features being
  from different scales.
- Save the mean and std you obtain during the training and use
  those values during the prediction phase for normalizing the test
  samples.
- Change the C value and see if that changes the results.

I hope these help.

Comment: Actually I'm normalizing them both train and test before splitting them, then since I had the same results as before I tried to add the weight